# Word or idiom for 'over-powered for the given collection of parts'

Tags: adjectives, idiom-requests

The specific passage I am writing is for people who propose to use a $2000 camera as a webcam. Unless their audio, lighting, and set are equal in quality to that camera, there is no reason spend that $2000, since all the other parts will limit the maximum quality of the whole.

A generic example would be in the Six-Millon Dollar Man program, where Steve Austin gets a bionic arm and legs and is shown being able to lift a car. In real life, his arm and legs could theoretically take the weight of the car, but his shoulder, torso, and pelvis would be crushed.

What word or idiom can I use to describe the camera (or the bionic arm)? I would prefer it to be more humorous than bookish, if you know what I mean.

Comment: A chain is only as strong as its weakest link.

Comment: That is a saying I often use in conversations, when I have a few sentences to describe the idea. However, to do that in writing would require further explanation like 'which is why it the bionic arm does not help Steve lift the car.'  I am really dowsing for a single word or idiom that describes the component that is overly strong.

Comment: Ah, yes--something like "that link is too strong for the chain", the meaning of which wouldn't be immediately obvious to me without explanation. I don't think it's a common idiom or proverb. That is why I didn't make it an answer; but it may jog someone's memory. Cheers!

Comment: If you wanted to talk customers out of the expensive camera, you could say it's *overkill*. But are you?

Comment: It is not a sales relationship, so persuasion is not a factor. 'Overkill' does not have any notion of comparing it to other components in the system. 'Using a sledgehammer to crack a nut' is similarly narrower in scope to what I am looking for.

Comment: Have settled on "a platinum link in a paper chain'. Not perfect, but it will have to do...